# Is it possible to get the information dropped into a droppable div and storing it in a database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to drag and drop nametags see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/132/) and store the ones dragged into the droppable divs and later put them in my database. So I would basically want to check and see if there are values in the droppable box and have a submit button. And upon the submit action I would want to make sure values were in the droppable div and store the data in a database. I'm wondering if I could use `<?php isset() ?>` with a query either by including jquery with it (if possible) or just do it using jquery alone (if possible) maybe using the `val()` property.I would be greatly appreciative to know if what I'm asking is possible as well as any other tips that may help me moving forward.

Comment: Why don't you just run some ajax on the event?

Comment: I'm not following you. How so? @bigman

Comment: Someone else answered it, he's on track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#sortcard, #dropbox, #dropbox1').droppable({
    accept: '.sorting',
    hoverClass: 'border',
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(e, ui) {

    ...

    $.post("ajax.php", 
          {data: $(this).text()}, 
          function(data) {
               alert("Data saved.");
          });
    }
});​
```

Make your AJAX call in the "drop" event.